# linear map notation question

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In Axler's book *Linear Algebra Done Right*, he uses the symbol $\cal L$ to denote  the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$. Is there a different notation (that's maybe easier to write)? Also, is this a common notation, or is it specific to Axler?

Comment: Axler, Artin.  Look alike I guess.

Comment: I know this symbol to denote the *set* of linear maps from one vector space to another, e.g. $\mathcal L(E,F)$ – it avoids confusion with the $L^p$ spaces, where the $L$ stands for Lebesgue – but never saw it used  for a given linear map.

Comment: Practice writing script letters because they are used a lot in math. I suggest this guide, https://www.aresearchguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/4.png The L is actually fairly easy once you practice a few times. Your script L doesn't have to match Axler's exactly, it just has to be distinct enough from your usual L so that you and others know it's different.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Script and calligraphic are different $\mathscr L\mathcal L$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor it's irrelevant, there is nothing special about script or calligraphic except that they serve to differentiate between various objects we would like to call L. I said script but I could have just as easily said calligraphic or gothic, etc.

Comment: @TonyS.F. You never know

Comment: Why have you a problem with this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $K$-linear maps are the (homo)morphisms of the category of $K$-vector spaces, it is perfectly valid (though not very common) to write $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ for the set (in fact $K$-vector space) of linear maps from $V$ to $W$.